# IsSetData in gridcontrol is never true when clicking on checkEdit item

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have this `DevExpress GridContro`l which I've added with two coloums the one containing a `repositoryItemCheckEdit` and the other normal `string` Category description.

Now I've made the `repositoryItemCheckEdit` a unbound bool in the property section and added the `gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData` event which fires with `e.IsGetData` true but the the `e.IsSetData` is never true when I click on the check box. Can anyone explain why this is? 
Thanks

```
private void gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, CustomColumnDataEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.IsGetData)
  {
    string itemKey = ((CategoryTable)(gridControl1.ViewCollection[0]).GetRow(e.RowHandle)).Category;
    if (AddressDoc == itemKey) e.Value = true
    else e.Value = false;
  }

  if (e.IsSetData)
    AddressDoc = ((CategoryTable)(gridControl1.ViewCollection[0]).GetRow(e.RowHandle)).Category;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the solution from the [How to save the value of an in-place check box as soon as it is changed](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/ViewKBIssue.aspx?kbid=A880) knowledge base article published on our web site.  It should help you resolve this problem.  Also, I have reviewed your code and it does not look to be safe.  I would change it as follows:

```
private void gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, CustomColumnDataEventArgs e) {
            GridView gridView = sender as GridView;
            DataView dv = gridView.DataSource;
            object c = DataView[e.ListSourceRowIndex]["Category"];
            string itemKey = c == null ? "" : c.ToString();
            if (e.IsGetData) {
                if(AddressDoc == itemKey)
                    e.Value = true;
                else 
                    e.Value = false;
            }
            if(e.IsSetData)
                AddressDoc = itemKey;
        }
```

I can only think that you did not properly adjusted the unbound column.  NOTE: a column should meet two mandatory conditions to be unbound: 
1) it's FieldName should be set to a unique value among fieldName properties of other GridView columns; 
2) the column's UnboundType should be set to the non Bound value.

Comment: I tried the `repositoryItemCheckEdit1_EditValueChanged` event which the link you provided explained I should use, but it never gets fired??

Comment: Please try to change the checkBox value and focus another record.  Do you see the problem in this case?

Comment: It seems the problem was lying in the class I was inheriting. I think it's overriding something which causes the events not to fire as they should. I went back to just inheriting The User Control directly and it fixes the problem.

Comment: It seems the problem was lying in the class I was inheriting from. I think it's overriding something which causes the events not to fire as they should. I went back to just inheriting The `UserControl` directly and it fixes the problem. O and the `gridView1.PostEditor()` helped allot. thanks